# Local file and cluster mode

Tags: apache-spark, cluster-computing

I'm just getting started using Apache Spark. I'm using cluster mode and I want to process a big file. I am using the textFile method from SparkContext, it will read a local file system available on all nodes.
Due to the fact my file is really big it is a pain to copy and paste in each cluster node. My question is: is there any way to have this file in a unique location like a shared folder?
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

You can keep the file in `Hadoop` or  `S3` . 
Then you can give the path of the file in `textFile` method itself .

for s3 :

```
val data = sc.textFile("s3n://yourAccessKey:yourSecretKey@/path/")
```

for hadoop :

```
val hdfsRDD  = sc.textFile("hdfs://...")
```